# Reference to function from another script

Tags: c#, function, reference, unity-game-engine

I have problem with referencing to function from another script. I really dont know what to do. I searched for solution, but i didn't understand that.
Can someone say what I'm doing wrong?

First script[dotykxd.cs]:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

 public class dotykxd : MonoBehaviour {


void Start()
{




    }
// Use this for initialization


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if(Input.touches.Length <=0)
    {

    }

    else{

        for(int i=0; i< Input.touchCount;i++)
        {
            if(this.guiTexture.HitTest(Input.GetTouch(i).position))
            {/*
                if(Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
                {
                    Camera.main.backgroundColor=Color.black;
                }*/

                if(Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    obrot obrotek= GetComponents<obrot> ();
                    obrot.obr();

                }


            }
        }

    }
      }
  }
```

Another script[obrot.cs]

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

 public class obrot : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 5f;


// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    obr ();


}

void obr ()
{
    transform.Translate(new Vector3(1,0,0) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call a function from another script you need to have a reference to that [**GameObject**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) or script [**Component**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.html) attached to that GameObject.

If you have reference to GameObject you can simply use [**SendMessage**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SendMessage.html) like this:

```
gameObjReference.SendMessage("NameOfFunction");
```

If you have the reference to the script you can just call the function like this:

```
scriptReference.FunctionName();
```

---

However, your bigger problem is going to be, how do you get these references.

```
GameObject gameObjReference = GameObject.Find("Name of GameObject in Scene");
```

That is, you put the name of the GameObject, what ever you called it in the scene.

The other method is similar.

```
ScriptName scriptReference = GameObject.Find("Name of GameObject").GetComponent<ScriptName>();
```